# Super keyword ambiguity

Tags: java, super

The following program

```
class Feline {
    public String type = "f ";

    public Feline() {
        System.out.print("feline ");
    }
}

public class Cougar extends Feline {

    public Cougar() {
        System.out.print("cougar ");
    }

    void go() {
        type = "d ";
        System.out.print(this.type + super.type);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Cougar().go();
    }
}
```

produces the following output.

```
feline cougar d d
```

I am not able to understand why `super.type` did not fetch the value of the from the superclass while producing the output and printed an `f` instead of printing the local value `d`. Can some one please provide some help here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the inverse, now your `type` are merged together, when you change the value of `type`, it is overwriting the `super.type`.

Here a short example as explanation:

```
void go() {
    System.out.print(this.type);
    type = "d ";
    System.out.print(this.type + super.type);
}
```

Output:

```
f d d
```

It is actually changing the `super.type` value `f` to `d`

Comment: +1. It's worth noting that the OP *can* give `Cougar` a separate variable `type`, but in that case (s)he needs to explicitly declare it in `Cougar`. (And that separate variable can even have a completely different type; for example, `private int type = 3;` is completely fine.)

Comment: @Jonathan Would it mean if an instance variable defined in superclass (`type` in this case) and NOT in subclass, once modified anywhere in the subclass will eventually lead `this.type` and `super.type` to have same effect ?

Comment: True this is it! I'm glad you got the picture, as object oriented is neat when we got the whole picture. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Trying to explain classes and objects in a simple way:

Think classes as archetypes or models for objects.
When you create class B extending a class A (other), it means that the model B has all the behaviors of A plus the some extra behaviors.  Furthermore, B can also override(substitute) some behaviors from A.

Until now, we said nothing about the objects yet.

Now, within `main()` you are creating the object (also called, an instance) of type B.

You have only a single object. Therefore, you have only one state.  It's not one state for each class, because the state related to the instance.
It means, `type` in you code, is from this single object. It doesn't matter whether you refer to it from `this` or `super`.

---

You can reach a different behavior between `this` and `super` if you override a method, and then, call those methods.

Try it out:
create a method `sayHello()` in the Feline class, printing some text. Then, create another `sayHello()` in the Cougar class, with a different text.
Then, inside `go()`, call:
`this.sayHello(); 
super.sayHello();`

Answer (score 0):

Because unless you make each `type` attribute `private`, the `type` is visible and **the same** across all the children of parent class (`Feline`): you don't change `Cougar`' `type`, but `Feline`' `type` because it is inherited.

This example should make it clearer:

```
class A {
  private String type;
  public String getType() {return type;}
}

class B extends A {
  private int type;

  public void go() {
    System.out.println("this.type: " + this.type + ", super.type: "+  super.getType());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new B().go(); // prints: this.type: 0, super.type: null
  }
}
```